# how to print files name having same name just a character difference in perl

Tags: perl

I have files in folder named `SRR1425702_1.txt`, `SRR1425702_2.txt`, `SRR1425709_1.txt`, `SRR1425709_2.txt`. I want to print the files with the same prefix (the part before `_`) on the same line, separated by tabs.

```
SRR1425702_1.txt<TAB>SRR1425702_2.txt
SRR1425709_1.txt<TAB>SRR1425709_2.txt
```

Comment: @serenesat :   elsif($_ =~ m/(\w+)(_\w+.*).txt/){ 
  if($_ =~m/(\w+)(_\w+.*.txt)/){
 print"$1\t$2\n"; } }

Answer (score 1):

Grouping is usually done using hashes.

```
my %files_by_prefix;
for my $file (@files) {
   my ($prefix) = $file =~ /^([^_]+)_/
      or next;

   push @{ $files_by_prefix{$prefix} }, $file;
}

for my $prefix (sort keys %files_by_prefix) {
   print(join("\t", sort @{ $files_by_prefix{$prefix} }), "\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks dear!!! but it is printing multiple times. i want to print only one time

Comment: Huh, no it doesn'. You must have duplicates in @files. How did you read the folder?!